# How would you go about understanding the networking of a game and doing your own server?

Tags: networking, packet

I'm trying to reverse the network of a game. The commands are strings, however, it's not as easy as getting the function that encrypts the packet, as it's not encrypted, just encoded in its own way, however, I'm having trouble finding what function encodes/decodes the packets sent/received, because it's probably nested in a bunch of functions.

Debugging the server, I set a memory breakpoint on the function that reads the socket and gets the packet, but I had no success, the memory got accessed a bunch of times and it probably gets copied somewhere amidst the accesses.

So what's the thought process you have when you're reversing a network? What tools can I use to help me? I tried using signsearch to get what encrypted the packets, but it's not encrypted by a famous algorithm. If I capture a bunch of packets, and if I know the command those packets mean, ex: "smile", can I do something to relate the command to the various packets?